# Let $G$ be a group of order $16$ with an element $g$ of order $4$. Prove that the subgroup of $G$ generated by $g^2$ is normal in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Question: Let $G$ be a group of order $16$ with an element $g$ of order $4$.  Prove that the subgroup of $G$ generated by $g^2$ is normal in $G$.

Thoughts: I keep getting stuck.  My most recent path is that since $G$ is solvable, then there is a subnormal series... so maybe I can get something to come out there?  But I just feel like a counterexample is throwing a wrench into everything I try.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Presumably, you do not know a classification of groups of order 16?

Comment: Since $\vert g^2 \vert=2$, this is equivalent to showing that $g^2 \in Z(G)$.

Comment: The critical case you need to consider is where $Z(G)$ has order $2$ and $N_G(H)$ has order $8$, $H$ being the cyclic subgroup of interest. 

If $H$ intersects $Z(G)$ non-trivially, you are done because the unique proper non-trivial subgroup of $H$ is central thus normal. You can assume therefore that $H \cap Z(G) = 1$. 

If the order of $Z(G)$ is at least $4$, then the whole group is central-by-cyclic thus abelian whence all subgroups are normal. You can thus assume that $Z(G)$ has order $2$.

Also, if $H$ is normal then it intersects $Z(G)$ non-trivially. Thus $N_G(H)$ has order $8$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a hint. Let $H=\langle g\rangle$. Now, consider the action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$. Since $|G:H|=4$, this gives you a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_4$. Since $16$ does not divides $|S_4|$, this homomorphism cannot be injective. What can you say about the kernel?

Comment: Delightful! ${}$

Comment: @verret So, the kernal is non-trivial and so the kernal has order $2$ or $4$.... I suppose I'm not yet wrapping my head around the conclusion...

Comment: Yes, and kernels are normal subgroups. Also, the kernel has to be contained in $H$.

Comment: @verret Okay, that makes sense, but how do we know that the kernal is generated by $g^2$?

Comment: @User7238 We don't. But a characteristic subgroup of a normal subgroup is itself normal. Or, more simply, if $g$ generates a normal subgroup, surely $\langle g^2\rangle$ is normal also.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ahhh, I see, that is very nice.  Thank you!

Comment: @verret, why can't we take simpler approach. since ${|<g>| =4}$, then subgroup generated by ${<g^2>}$ has order 2, so the subgroup contains ${\{ g^2,e\}}$, so ${ (g^2)^2=e}$, subgroup is abelian and hence normal.

Comment: @SSA An abelian subgroup is not necessarily normal. Consider any subgroup of $S_3$ generated by a 2-cycle. May be you confuse it with the fact that if $G$ is abelian and $H\le G$ then also $H\unlhd G$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, oh.. ok, But how do we find that ${\{g^2,e\}}$ falls into the kernel of homomorphism of  ${f:G \mapsto S_4}$ . we've each left coset of H maps to one vertex of S4. But how to derive , that   ${\{g^2,e\}}$  the kernel of G maps to identify of ${S_4}$ ?

Comment: @SSA See my reply to User7238's comment above. The kernel is a non-trivial subgroup of $\langle g\rangle$ so it is either $\langle g\rangle$ or $\langle g^2\rangle$. The latter is normal in both cases.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen,   ${g^2}$ has order 2. i.e., ${|G|=16}$ , now, Theorem says, if G has a subgroup of  the order of smallest prime factor of order of G, then that subgroup is normal to G. Is it not correct?

Comment: @SSA There is no such theorem. Again $S_3$ has counterexamples. May be you remember a theorem saying that if $[G:H]=p$ where $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$ then $H$ is normal? In other words, you confused *order* and *index*.

Comment: Or more obviously, the result you misremembered would claim that every simple group is cyclic of prime order because by Cauchy it has a subgroup of order $p$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, revisiting my notes, I found, index theorem; here, H is a proper subgroup of G and ${|G|}$ does not divide ${|G:H|!}$, then H contains a non trivial normal subgroup of G.

Comment: @SSA Yes, if you check the proof of that theorem, it goes exactly as in my answer: consider the homomorphism to the symmetric group, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Verret's solution is very nice, and surely how it is meant to be done. But here is another way:

Note that we aim to prove that $g^2$ is central, so assume not. Let $H=C_G(g)$. If $H=G$ then $g\in Z(G)$, so $g^2\in Z(G)$, a contradiction. Since $Z(G)$ is non-trivial and contained in $H$, and does not contain $g^2$, $H$ must be $\langle g\rangle \times Z(G)$ (with $|Z(G)|=2$). (This is purely because $Z(G)$ centralizes $g$ and so forms a direct product.) But then $H$ is normal, so $G$ normalizes the set of squares of elements of $H$, i.e., $\{1,g^2\}$. Hence $H^2$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and done.

Edit: Here's another proof, using a fact that everyone should know: any two elements of order $2$ generate a dihedral group.

Let $x=g^2$. Since $x$ is non-central, there is a conjugate $y$ of $x$ with $x\neq y$. Consider $H=\langle x,y\rangle$, a dihedral group. Since the reflections in dihedral groups aren't squares, $g\notin H$. Also, two generating reflections in a dihedral $2$-group, like $H$, are not conjugate in $H$. Thus $H\leq C_G(x)$. Thus, since $H$ and $g$ are contained in the proper subgroup $C_G(x)$, we have $|H|=4$, i.e., $x$ commutes with its conjugate $y$. Notice also that $g$ must commute with $y$ as well, so $\langle g,y\rangle=\langle g\rangle \times \langle y\rangle$. In this group, $y$ is not a square. But $y$ is conjugate to $x$, which is a square, so $y=h^2$ for some $h\in G$. But $h$ centralizes $x$ for the same reason that $g$ centralized $y$. Hence $C_G(x)> \langle g,y\rangle$, and is thus the whole group $G$.

Comment: Very nice!  Thank you so much!